# Issue with Keypress (Post QUERY incomplete)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm developing an auto-complete suggest form with jQuery, My problem is that KEYPRESS sends POST Request with an incomplete Query (rest -1 character to real query).

Here is the jQuery code:

```
    $(function(){

      search = $(".left");
      search_input = $(".left input.text");
      search_input.click(function(){
            $(".left form").append("<div class=\"search-capa admitido\"></div>");
            search_capa = $(".search-capa");
            result_search_capa = $(".search-capa");

      })


      $(".left value.text").keypress(function(){
              value = $(".left input.text").val();
              value = value.replace(" ","+");
              console.log(value);
              getConec(value);
      })

      function getConec(kery){
            $.post("suggest.php",{q:kery},function(data){
                  result_search_capa.html(data);
                  var li = $('.search-capa a');
                  var liSelected;
                  moveoption()
            })
      }
      function moveoption(){
                  $(document).keydown(function(e){
                      if(e.which === 40){
                          if(liSelected){
                              liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                              next = liSelected.next();
                              if(next.length > 0){
                                  liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                                  $('.left input.text').val(liSelected.text());

                              }else{
                                  liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
                                  $('.left input.text').val(liSelected.text());
                              }
                          }else{
                              liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
                              $('.left input.text').val(liSelected.text());
                          }
                      }else if(e.which === 38){
                          if(liSelected){
                              liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                              next = liSelected.prev();
                              if(next.length > 0){
                                  liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                                  $('.left input.text').val(liSelected.text());
                              }else{
                                  liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
                                  $('.left input.text').val(liSelected.text());
                              }
                          }else{
                              liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
                              $('.left input.text').val(liSelected.text());

                          }
                      }
                  });
      }

})
```

If I search for "Web developer" the POST request sends "Web develope" (the last character is always missing). Why? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keypress` event is firing before the key that was pressed is passed to the input ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a08brqwr/)).  Instead try something like this: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a08brqwr/1/))

```
$('.left value.text').on('keyup', function() {
    var value = $(".left value.text").val();
    value = value.replace(" ","+");
    getConec(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case $('.left .text').on('keypress', function() { it works perfectly :)